# Create Dynamic Web controls Without Switch or IFElse

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am Working on page where I get value from database of what type of control I have to create.

If I get `TextBox` in my hidden field from database, I have to create `TextBox` dynamically, If I get `Dropdown` in hidden field, I have to create Dropdown and so on...

I know how to create Dynamic textboxes, here is reference link : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-create-and-read-values-of-dynamic-controls-in-Asp-Net/

Using example, I can check `IF Control TYPE = TEXTBOX` then create `TextBox` and so on.

But, How I can do this without using `IF ELSE` or `CASE` statement in my function? Any ideas guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

Map a control name from the DB to the .NET type name of the control, e.g:

```
 var types new Dictionary<string, string>();
 types.Add("TextBox", "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox, System.Web");
 var controlType = "TextBox";

 var control = (WebControl) 
                 Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(types[controlType]));

 // use control instance here
```

Comment: This approach is the way to go. An alternative to calling Activator.CreateInstance is to create a factory that instantiates your objects and returns them too, but it's more code.

Comment: Factory method is a suitable abstraction here, and there is no reason why the implementation of the factory can not be the Activator.CreateInstance

Comment: Just testability concerns if anything.